# How to fill a dynamic textbox with a text from another textbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code

```
var rowCount = $('#tblApplIdn tr').length;
var index = rowCount + 1;
$('#tblApplIdn').append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='identitity.Index' value='" + index + "' /><input type='text'  name='identitity[" + index + "].TypeOfIdentification' value=" + $('#TypeOfIdentification').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq' name='identitity[" + index + "].IdentityNumber' value=" + value + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  name='identitity[" + index + "].IssueDate' value=" + $('#IssueDate').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  name='identitity[" + index + "].ExpiryDate' value=" + $('#ExpiryDate').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  name='identitity[" + index + "].DateReceived' value=" + $('.receivedDte').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  name='identitity[" + index + "].IssuingAuthority' value=" + $('.issAuthority').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  name='identitity[" + index + "].PlaceofIssue' value=" + $('#PlaceofIssue').val() + "></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  value=" + $('#Countryofissue option:selected').text() + "><input type='hidden' class='textreq'   name='identitity[" + index + "].Countryofissue' value=" + $('#Countryofissue').val() + "></td><td><input type='button' name='remove' class='remove' value='Remove' id='" + index + "'/></tr>");
```

The above code does not fill the dynamic textbox properly. Suppose if I say  IdentityNumber=AA 1234 then the dynamic textbox only takes AA and does not fill anything after space. I tried taking a variable and then assigned the value to that variable and then this variable when passed as a value still it behaves the same way. I have around 12 tab and almost all tab needs dynamic textboxes to be added upon clicking Add button and the user have the option to add multiple records. Within inspect element I can find

```
<input type="text" class="textreq valid" name="identitity[2].IdentityNumber" value="AA" 1234 aria-invalid="false">
```

How to include the entire value within dynamic Textbox. I browsed and tried all I could find but it doesn't works. Any comments and answer's are really appreciated.

Comment: You're not properly quoting the code.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal can u please post the quoting code as you said an example in the answer section and if that fits my requirement I will mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: should be like this:) name="identitity['" + index + "'].TypeOfIdentification"

Comment: @BhojendraNepal what does name has to do here.

Comment: Can you inspect Element and then check for this button id='" + index + what is it???

Comment: Can you explain bit more about this!! An example or fiddle would be great to work around!!

Comment: @JunaidAhmed I have a add button and upon click the user can add multiple <tr> as above and in order to identify the button and all input elements i have declared a variable which is incremented everytime when a new <tr> is appended. See my updated question.

Comment: Its not like **it does not fill**.. It's because you keeping the value `1234` outside quotes. You need to put it inside quotes like `value="AA 1234"`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao and how do you think I can do that plz let me know.

Comment: I said in your html where you have quoted value its outside the `" "` See you have `value="AA" 1234` in html `input` that should be changed to  `value="AA 1234"`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yeah exactly but how should I put it in the dynamic textbox.

Comment: Can you create an example in **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I haven't created any fiddle so far but tried doing it as per your suggenstion and it seems blunder. sorry for that can you please check it https://jsfiddle.net/r7dLpybg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This might not be an optimal solution but just to achieve the requirement you can use it!! Even I am not sure why you are not able to append values with space so What I am gonna do is store the values in each variable and then get it assigned to each `input` of last `tr`s `td` as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/r7dLpybg/4/)**

```
$('.btnApplIdnDtls').click(function () {
    var rowCount = $('#tblApplIdn tr').length;
    var index = rowCount + 1;
    var IndentifyType=$('#TypeOfIdentification option:selected').text();//get values
    var IdentifyNum=$("#IdentityNumber").val();//get values
    var IssueDate=$('#IssueDate').val();//get values
    $('#tblApplIdn').append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='identitity.Index' value='" + index + "' /><input type='text'  name='identitity[" + index + "].TypeOfIdentification'></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq' name='identitity[" + index + "].IdentityNumber'></td><td><input type='text'  class='textreq'  name='identitity[" + index + "].IssueDate'></td><td><input type='button' name='remove' class='remove' value='Remove' id='" + index + "'/></tr>");//simply append it
    var lasttr=$('#tblApplIdn tr:last'); //get the last tr
    lasttr.find('td:first input[type="text"]').val(IndentifyType); give its input a value
    lasttr.find('td:nth-child(2) input').val(IdentifyNum);
    lasttr.find('td:nth-child(3) input').val(IssueDate);
});
```